# Robot Framework: why does Log ignore my argument?

Tags: runtime-error, robotframework

When I run the code below I get an error message

```
Keyword 'BuiltIn.Log' expected 1 to 5 arguments, got 0.
```

for the second `log to console` (within the if-clause). Why? Why doesn't it "see" the variable I try to send as an argument?

Googling doesn't return anything useful. I have tried several combinations of spaces and apostrophes but nothing has worked.

```
Function key above F12
    [Arguments]  ${fkey}
    ${ValidFKeys}=    Create List    F13  F14  F15  F16  F17
    log to console  ${fkey}
    Run Keyword If   $fkey in $ValidFKeys  run keywords
    ... log to console  ${fkey}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Run Keywords documentation:

> By default all arguments are expected to be keywords to be executed.

What happened is `Run Keywords` treated `Log To Console` as the first keyword to be ran, then the value of `${fkey}` as the second - it did not pass it as argument to the log. To overcome this, add an "AND" - so now it knows `${fkey}` is an argument; if yo udon't have any other keyword to be ran, either drop `Run Keywords`, or use `No Operation`:

```
Run Keyword If   $fkey in $ValidFKeys  run keywords
... log to console  ${fkey}  AND  No Operation
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Run Keyword` [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword) not be a better choice?

Comment: If it's a single keyword to be ran, then using `Run Keyword` is redundant - `Run Keyword If` by itself runs a single one.

Comment: Seems to work. How come `Send special key   Shift` doesn't require a `AND  No operation`? Isn't `Shift` an argument to `Send special key`, similar to how a string is logged?

Comment: It is worth adding that `No operation` isn't necessary if you have more lines following your first line, which you should if you use `run keywordS`.

Comment: > "It is worth adding that No operation isn't necessary if you have more lines" - that's right, I've put the `No Operation` precisely to have more than 1 line :). I can't comment why `Send special key Shift` worked without the AND with no code sample; perhaps it was one of a series of keywords? If it was the sole one passed to `Run Keywords`, then the same error would have been logged.